# Is attribute-based encryption used to encrypt data and apply access control, or only do the latter?

Tags: encryption, abe

I am trying to decide whether to encrypt data by using attribute-based encryption or use an encryption algorithm such as AES before using attribute-based encryption.

Is attribute-based encryption used to encrypt data and apply access control, or only do the latter?

Comment: Attribute-Based **Encryption** schemes provide the confidentiality of the message and you don't need to pre-encrypt the data.

Comment: @Mahdi, confidentiality means hide the original data with providing access control, so if i want to encrypt data by using Attribute based Encryption means that data is encrypted like using any ther encryption algorithm e.g. AES.